# Express API DELETE

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I am trying to add DELETE to my api, but am getting a 404: Not Found for everything I try. All of the GET and POST methods work. This is using the "Points" model that contains points, each with a unique id. I am trying to add a call to delete a point by its id.

Action

```
export function deletePointById(identifier) {
    return dispatch => {
        return axios.delete('/api/points/' + identifier)
    }
}
```

Route for DELETE (doesn't work)

```
router.delete('/:identifier', (req, res) => {
    Points.remove({
      id: req.params.identifier
    }), function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return res.send(err);
      }

      res.json({ message: 'Deleted' });
    };
});
```

Here is an existing GET that works fine

Action

```
export function getPointsBySession(session){
    return dispatch => {
        return axios.get('/api/points/session/' + session)
    }
}
```

Route for GET

```
router.get('/session/:session', (req, res) => {
    Points.query({
      select: ['id', 'number', 'quadrant', 'level', 'title', 'category'],
      where: {sessionId: req.params.session}
    }).fetchAll().then(point => {
      res.json({ point });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue might be that theres an extra brace and semicolon ( `};`) in your code:

```
router.delete('/:identifier', (req, res) => {
    Points.remove({
      id: req.params.identifier
    }), function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return res.send(err);
      }

      res.json({ message: 'Deleted' });
    }; // <-- HERE
});
```

You also need to remove the semicolon on the line above the one I added the comment to.

It will look like this:

```
router.delete('/:identifier', (req, res) => {
    Points.remove({
      id: req.params.identifier
    }), function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return res.send(err);
      }

      res.json({ message: 'Deleted' })
});
```